# How to calculate the Voting Power of any validator address?

Tags: voting, aptos

I am confused in how to calculate the voting power for any validator address. I am thinking and it also seems like we have to add the **active** and **pending_inactive** value.
For ex: for address: 0x4e28ca55c3ccde886560d667d60cd2d1193e742ff5aede3ba93b3860a97e207f

---

If i am adding the active and pending_inactive, it is giving me the correct value mentioned on the explorer.
It would be great if anyone can verify this.

I have added active and pending_inactive and getting the voting power. I just wanted to verify that if it's a correct way or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong but the approach you've mentioned – adding active and pending_inactive values to determine voting power – is a common pattern in various Proof of Stake (PoS) or Delegated Proof of Stake (DPoS) systems. Active votes may represent the currently active stake, while pending_inactive could represent stakes that are pending activation or deactivation. Chai

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).